# Transpose data with reshape2 with data airquality

Tags: r

I want to reshape the data airquality. I want "Month" on the row and all other as columns.  I made the columns unique by adding the month and day number. It works to transform but nearly all the values get NA. Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

```
airquality
library(reshape2)
aql <- melt(airquality, id.vars=c("Month", "Day"))
aql$variable <- paste0(airquality$Month, airquality$Day, aql$variable)
aql <- aql[,-2]
aqw <- dcast(aql, Month~variable
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this exercise? Are you simply want to get the 5 lines of monthly average for Ozone, Solar Radiation, Wind and Temperature? Or is there a reason why you want to create a 5 x 613 data.frame, each with a unique column for each month-year?

Comment: This mimik a dataset I work with, we want to apply imputation after collecting several questionnaires in this format. Each ID should be on one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution by @Chris is neat, but as `pivot_wider` is a new function from the development version, it might be subject to breaking changes in the future and is not well suited to produce code, that is supposed to stay replicable. Using the CRAN version you can do the same with just a little more code:

```r
library(tidyr)

airquality %>% 
  gather("var", "value", Ozone:Temp) %>% 
  unite("name", var, Day) %>% 
  spread(name, value)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to keep the unique months in the first colum? Five rows, (month 5,6,7,8,9), and then comes all the columns with values?

Comment: Or no, now I realize everything got NA again. Why is this? Do you have an idea how I can solve this? I added a new column with id.   

 gather <- gather(airquality,"var", "value", Ozone:Temp)
head(gather)
unite <- unite(gather,"name", var,Month, Day) 
head(unite)
id <- unite(gather,"id", Month)
head(id)
unite$id <- id$id
airquality <- spread(unite,name, value)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but you definitely shouldn't assign your data to objects with the names of functions you want to use, that will result in errors

Comment: You are completely right, I shouldn't!
airg <- gather(airquality,"var", "value", Ozone:Temp)
head(airg)
airu <- unite(airg,"name", var,Month, Day) 
head(airu)
id <- unite(airg,"id", Month)
head(id)
airu$id <- id$id
airquality <- spread(airu,name, value)
I want there to be one row for each month,5,6,7,8,9 and all the variables for each month as columns, and then the values can be read on the same row for each month

Comment: @shs agree this is sensible advice given it is the development version. I still think it's good to recommend the use of pivot over `gather` since the latter will be retired in the next cran release so switching over sooner will be less bothersome

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the new `pivot_wider` function from the [development version](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr) of `tidyr` which is quite intuitive:

```r
#devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")
library(tidyr)


airquality %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Month,
              names_from = Day,
              values_from = c(Ozone, Solar.R, Wind, Temp)) 


## A tibble: 5 x 125
#  Month Ozone_1 Ozone_2 Ozone_3 Ozone_4 Ozone_5 Ozone_6 Ozone_7 Ozone_8 Ozone_9 Ozone_10
#  <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>    <int>
#1     5      41      36      12      18      NA      28      23      19       8       NA
#2     6      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      29      NA      71       39
#3     7     135      49      32      NA      64      40      77      97      97       85
#4     8      39       9      16      78      35      66     122      89     110       NA
#5     9      96      78      73      91      47      32      20      23      21       24
## … with 114 more variables
```

This creates a column for each air quality variable and day, and a row for each month.

Note that `reshape2` (2010-2014) is [retired](https://github.com/hadley/reshape) and replaced by `tidyr` so it's worth looking into.